# VirtualBox / MAAS Port Forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, virtualbox, internal-dns, dns-server

i have 4 VM's in VirtualBox on an Ubuntu 17.04 desktop computer, which is connected to a MAAS subnet.

each VM is configured with Apache and OpenSSH, for one of 4 domains i have.

my problem is that i only have one 80 port and one 22 port on my router, and i want to forward the ports to the right VM by the requesting domain; for example:

ssh user@domain1.com -> domain1.com_VM

ssh user@domain2.com -> domain2.com_VM

thanks in advance

Comment: Your questions could be improved a lot by using a proper grammar, chat style isn't very popular here.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible for HTTP port `80` as the `HTTP/1.1` protocol has `Host:` header for identifying the hostname i.e. domain. You'd need to have a reverse proxy that handles all the connections and uses the correct VM as a back-end server, based on the `Host:` header. If your router can't work as one, you could utilize one VM for that and port forward `80` to it.

For SSH port `22` you simply can't do the same, because the protocol doesn't have a way to mediate the hostname used for the connection: after resolving correct IP from the DNS only the IP address is used for the connection.

Comment: ok, so how do you recommend doing that?

Comment: With Apache, see the documentation for [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html). It has suitable examples.